# PHP-GoogleAPI: URL shorther API doesnot provide short URL on localhost

Tags: php

am developing web application with a lot of forms enclosed in it.
I am using google's public link generation API.

```
<?php 
include 'config.php';
include 'php/lib/google_api/googleURL_shortener.php';
?>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <?php
    try {
        $key = "AIzaSyCzDa3nhryO23Aa-0VlxasYkZ-PPqeWfrY";
        $googleApi = new GoogleURL($key);
        $publicLink = '';

        $url = BASE_URL.'form_operation/index.php?    id=54ccb4db64363d9c1100002d';
        $publicLink = $googleApi->encode($url);

        echo $publicLink;

    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        echo $ex;
    }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

i have included google shortener API library Code for api library is this

```
<?php 

class GoogleURL 
{

 private $apiURL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url';

 function __construct($apiKey)
 {

  $this->apiURL = $this->apiURL . '?key=' . $apiKey;
 }

 public function encode($url)
 {
  $data = $this->cURL($url, true);

  return isset($data->id) ? $data->id : 'No data present' ;
 }

 public function decode($url)
 {
  $data = $this->cURL($url, false);
  return isset($data->analytics->allTime->shortUrlClicks) ? $data- >analytics->allTime->shortUrlClicks : 0 ;
 }

 private function cURL($url, $post = true)
 {

  $ch = curl_init();

  if ($post) {
   curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->apiURL );// cURL defined

   curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json') );
   curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
   curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode(array('longUrl' => $url)) );
  }
  else {
   curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->apiURL . '&projection=FULL&shortUrl=' . $url );
  }
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
  $json = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  return (object) json_decode($json);
  }
  }

 ?>
```

I am getting null output every time i call API from localhost.

I am getting following reply

```
stdClass Object
(
[error] => stdClass Object
    (
        [errors] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [domain] => usageLimits
                        [reason] => ipRefererBlocked
                        [message] => There is a per-IP or per-Referer    restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your API key configuration if request from this IP or referer should be allowed.
                        [extendedHelp] => https://console.developers.google.com
                    )

            )

        [code] => 403
        [message] => There is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your API key configuration if request from this IP or referer should be allowed.
    )
```

)

what can be done about it??

Comment: did you echoing $url to see if it's returning correct url??

Comment: Since localhost is not a valid URL on the internet, it can be expected that URL shortener returns null.

Comment: no no guys...actually i am getting different reply see the edited part